# Creating OGC Services via GeoServer automatically?

Tags: geoserver, web-service, java, ogc

I am new to GeoServer and wonder how I can create OGC Services via Geoserver automatically. I have to publish my data (Shapefiles) with a Java program as OGC Services. How can I do that?

I checked out the source code of GeoServer, but I don't know how to package as right jar file to use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by OGC services you mean WMS and WFS then you could use GeoServers REST configuration API, which lets you create workspaces, stores, styles, upload shapefiles etc. 
You can see a list of operations here:

[REST Configuration API Reference](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/rest-config-api.html)

GeoServer have examples of how to do this in cURL:

[GeoServer cURL REST examples](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.0.0/user/extensions/rest/rest-config-examples-curl.html)

I don't know much Java, but I am pretty sure you can convert the cURL examples to Java.