# Publishing Map on ArcGIS Server Manager without using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-server, postgresql

I want to publish my maps on sever manager.

My map data is in PostgreSQL and I want to connect it without using ArcGIS Desktop.

Is there any possibility to publish service without involving ArcGIS Desktop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the arcpy.mapping module in Python to do this without launching Desktop using the CreateMapSDDraft and StageService and UploadServiceDefinintion functions.

Code will look something like this:

```
import arcpy
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(<mxd>)
sddraft= <string representing path and name of sddraft>
service = <service name>
con = <path to server connection file (.ags)>
folder = <string representing where you want to publish the SD draft (default is root)>
sd = <path and name of of output service definition>

arcpy.mapping.CreateMapSDDraft(mxd,sddraft,service,"ARCGIS_SERVER",con,False, Folder)
 del mxd

arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)
arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, con)
```

Additionally, you can include arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForSD(sddraft) with an if/else statement to analyze your service definition prior to publishing and publish the service if no errors are found.

```
analysis = arcpy.mapping.AnalyzeForSD(sddraft)
if analysis['errors'] == {}:
        # Execute StageService
        arcpy.StageService_server(sddraft, sd)
        # Execute UploadServiceDefinition
        arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd, con)
        print (".....Map Service Created")
    else: 
        # If the sddraft analysis contained errors, display them
        print(analysis['errors'])
        print ("Service could not be published because errors were found during analysis.")
```

This does require having an ArcMap and ArcGIS for Server license, however.

Comment: But my employer is saying that I have to do everything using server and postgre database. I even can't use desktop for making .mxd. Just imagine I do not have arcgis desktop package on my machine. I hope it  make sense.

Comment: It would help to assign some different tags to your questions if you're not looking for an Arc-Desktop, Arc-Server solution.  Your best bet then is an OGC solution (like geoserver) to publish a WMS/WCS service.

Comment: sure! please edit my question.

Comment: In this case, it may be a duplicate.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15597/can-i-create-ogc-services-via-geoserver-automatically

Comment: It *doesn't* make sense to publish maps without a map publishing tool. Data in a database is just that -- bits on disk. In order to make maps, the data must be formatted, which in the GIS world means a mapping application. Once the drawing rules are established, those rules can be published to a mapping server.  It wold take weeks or months to develop a map in Python that would take minutes to build in Desktop.

Comment: _"my employer is saying ... I can't even use desktop for making .mxd"_ that and further to Vince's comments - you need Desktop. In the very least  you need it to get started. There are Python ways you can **modify** MXDs, but you can't make them from scratch. Publishing a map with just data and the server is like trying to bake a cake without measuring cups and mixing bowls: goodluck making something good with just the ingredients and the oven.

Comment: I am using Python remotely and I have an empty .mxd template. I am adding layers with the help of python scripting from server and I created sddraft too. so far everything is done without using ArcGIS desktop. BUT I am unable to execute the stage service script to create sd file.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Upload Service Definition (Server)](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00540000001p000000) and some of the code samples

Comment: But using Python window means I am still using ArcGIS Desktop indirectly. Am I right???

Comment: How I can make SD file without using ArcGIS Desktop

Comment: You don't have to use desktop at all, you can use the code in an IDE for isntance. Same with the create SD file code from your previous question.